# Invalid write of size 1

Tags: c, split, valgrind

I've fixed most of my split function that splits a original string according to a parameter into multiple ones saved in an array of strings: the program returns the values that i wanted but valgrind hits me with the following:

```
abc,defg
pasa
pasa
pasa
pasa
pasa
pasa
pasa
pasa
pasa
==2938== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2938==    at 0x4C2DB3C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2938==    by 0x400912: split (strutil.c:31)
==2938==    by 0x400A06: main (strutil.c:45)
==2938==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2938==    at 0x400723: split (strutil.c:9)
==2938== 
==2938== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2938==    at 0x4C31577: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2938==    by 0x40097F: split (strutil.c:34)
==2938==    by 0x400A06: main (strutil.c:45)
==2938==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2938==    at 0x400723: split (strutil.c:9)
==2938== 
==2938== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2938==    at 0x4C31631: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2938==    by 0x40097F: split (strutil.c:34)
==2938==    by 0x400A06: main (strutil.c:45)
==2938==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2938==    at 0x400723: split (strutil.c:9)
==2938== 
==2938== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2938==    at 0x4C3164F: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2938==    by 0x40097F: split (strutil.c:34)
==2938==    by 0x400A06: main (strutil.c:45)
==2938==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2938==    at 0x400723: split (strutil.c:9)
==2938== 
==2938== 
==2938== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==2938== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==2938== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==2938== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==2938== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==2938== 
abc
defg
```

And my code is:

```
#include "strutil.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(const char* str, char sep){
size_t cant = 2;
size_t i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
    if(str[i] == sep)
        cant ++;
}
size_t corte[cant];
corte[0] = 0;
size_t j = 1;
size_t cant_corte[cant];
for(i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    cant_corte[i] = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++){
    if(str[i] == sep || str[i] == '\0'){
        corte[j] = i + 1;
        cant_corte[j - 1] = corte[j] - corte[j - 1];
        j++;
    }
}

char** strv = malloc(sizeof(char*) * cant);
    if (strv == NULL)return NULL;
for(i=0; i < cant; i++){
    strv[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * cant_corte[i]); //line 30
    if (strv[i] == NULL)return NULL;
    memcpy(strv[i], str + corte[i], cant_corte[i]);
    strv[i][cant_corte[i] -1] = '\0'; //line 33
}
strv[cant - 1] = NULL;
return strv;
}

int main(){
char* eje = "abc,defg";
printf("%s\n", eje);
char r = ',';
char** prueba = split(eje, r);
printf("%s\n", prueba[0]);
printf("%s\n", prueba[1]);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I dont know where the problem is because it looks like it the same value thats  producing the problem but I can't seem to founf it

EDIT i edited the code and now valgrind displays me:

```
==3751== Invalid write of size 1
==3751==    at 0x4009DB: split (strutil.c:33)
==3751==    by 0x400A64: main (strutil.c:43)
==3751==  Address 0x520457f is 1 bytes before a block of size 0 alloc'd
==3751==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3751==    by 0x400949: split (strutil.c:30)
==3751==    by 0x400A64: main (strutil.c:43)
```

I've tried adding a +1 to the malloc on line 30 but instead says ...block of size 1 aloc'd... I've no idea and from what i researched its supposed to be that. thanks in advance

Comment: You declare `cant_corte[]` without initializing it, then you give it values only inside an `if`. The error is telling you that `cant_corte[i]` might not have a value at the point you're using it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `size_t cant_corte[cant];` is initialized as a VLA, isn't it?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker that gives me the more than a 10000000 errors valgrind displays me? and if it's so, how can i solve it? ty

Comment: `strncpy(strv[i], str + corte[i], cant_corte[i] - 1);
    strcat(strv[i], "\0");` : `strcar` requests a string terminated with `'\0'`. (Change it to like `memcpy(dest, src, length); dest[length] = '\0';`)

Comment: Why would your VLA be initialized? Do it yourself, either with a loop or with `memset()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you end up with `cant_corte[i]` is `0`, and then you `strv[i][cant_corte[i] -1] = '\0';`

so `strv[i][-1]` is not a valid address to write.

i do encourage you to learn how to use `valgrind` with `gdb` as explained at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-simple